# Can I use more than one HomePlug on the same electrical system?

Tags: networking, powerline-networking, hardware-selection

I'm trying to wire up an old college office (with 3 rooms) that has thick cement walls.  Running ethernet is painful, and wifi can't break through the concrete.

Can I use more than one [HomePlug](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Actiontec+-+500+Mbps+Powerline+Home+Theater+Network+Adapter+Kit/5215483.p?id=1218625358741&skuId=5215483&st=homeplug&cp=1&lp=1) to connect these 3 rooms to the main switch (which would have its own plug)

My thought is that the ethernet will broadcast the signal properly and that I don't have to worry about conflicts because the ethernet will handle the collisions appropriately.

Comment: If you couldn't use more than one, they'd be pretty useless. And what does Ethernet handling collisions have to do with anything?

Comment: thought was that if more than one was TX sending at the same time then there would be a collision.  Ethernet is simply placed on a new transport and I don't think that a conflict of multiple devices sending a TX at the same time is handled by the HomePlug... rather it's handled by a layer above that / Ethernet protocol  ... unless homeplug is a "bridge" and isolates the broadcast domain as such (where the broadcast is all electrical outlets before a filter , etc)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I have the situation you describe and have set up three HomePlug AV adapters (TPL-306E for reference) on the same network. All the computers/devices can "talk" to each other with no trouble as though it's an all Ethernet network.

Comment: I have four powerline devices and have running as two networks at times and one network at other times depending on what I am doing.  Works well for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. HomePlug AV Standard allows multiple adapters in one network. However, the number of adapters that you can use concurrently depends on how many RAM the adapters have. I'ld be quite sure that you can use a minimum of 4 adapters. If you need to use more adapters you should take a look at the adapter's specification.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least two - I currently have a pair of single port adaptors I got as a pair and a switch on the same network, though I'll be trying to add another unit. TP-Link's [documentation for their varient](http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?id=406) suggests that you can have 6-8 a network, but more than one network at once, while [netgear suggests](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20233/~/product-faqs-:-powerline-adapters.) 15-64 depending on the model.

However, even 6 is likely more than you'll need in your specific scenario.